# How to make tabs in VS Code to behave like tabs in Chrome?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I close a tab in VS Code it will open the previous opened tab, is there a setting to change this behavior? I would like it to behave like Chrome, when a tab is closed the next tab on the right will be opened.